# Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I tried to build crosstool in my raspberry pi, and the procedure I followed was from [How to compile FFmpeg for Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Raspberry%20Pi%20%28Raspbian%29). When I finished `ct-ng build`(which took a very long time), an error occurred. It shows that `Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs called in step '{top-level}'`

Here is the error I copied from build.log.

```
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_kernel_get[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@735]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@576]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/opt/cross/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.19.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]
```

How can I solve this? Please help me, I've already wasted 2 days on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Raspbian** is actually Debian. If you install the same version (7 or 8) on your host, then you can get a toolchain via [Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/). See this [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain) for more details. Example:

```
apt-get install g++-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Via `xapt` you install missing dependencies for cross-compilation.

Alternative approach were to use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). On one hand BR also has ct-ng backend, on the other hand you can create a complete root file system with it. BR also provides ffmpeg package.

.